# SSL Communication between Android Marshmallow and Java server

Tags: java, android, ssl, client-server, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an Android client and a Java Server that communicate with a SSL socket. The communication works well with an Android version < 6.0. With Android 6.0 I have this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:292)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1036)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:739)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:221)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(ObjectOutputStream.java:247)
```

This is my server code:

```
ServerSocket server = null;
Socket socket=null;
SSLContext ctx;
KeyManagerFactory kmf;
KeyStore ks;
try{
     char[] passphrase = "password".toCharArray();
     String keyfile = "keyName";
     ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
     kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
     ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
     ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyfile), passphrase);
     kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
     ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
     ServerSocketFactory ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
     server = ssf.createServerSocket(port);
}catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}               
while (true) {              
     socket = server.accept();
     new Thread(new WorkerThread(socket));                
}
```

This is my Android code:

```
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        InputStream in2 = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.server);
        store.load(in2, "password".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(store);
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslcontext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(),
                new SecureRandom());
        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = sslcontext
                .getSocketFactory();
        clientSocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(
                Constants.SERVER_HOST, port);
        ObjectInputStream obi = new ObjectInputStream(
                clientSocket.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream obs = new ObjectOutputStream(
                clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        obs.writeObject("text");
        obs.flush();
```

I have also tried to set the cipher suite but without result.